# How do I get Doxygen to link to a method of an Objective-C class?

Tags: objective-c, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen to document my Objective-C code, and so far it's working fine.

However, I've been searching for hours and I have not been able to find any way to link to a method.  For example:

```
@interface Example : NSObject {
}

/** This is an example method I want to link to. */
- (void)methodWithArgument:(NSString*)one andArgument:(NSString*)two;

/** I want a link to methodWithArgument:andArgument: but Doxygen
 *  doesn't seem to link the two.
 */
- (void)someOtherMethod;

@end
```

My expectation is for *methodWithArgument:andArgument:* to become a link to the appropriate method, but in the generated documentation, it is just plain text.

I have tried lots of other forms:

```
methodWithArgument:andArgument:
-methodWithArgument:andArgument:
::methodWithArgument:andArgument:
Example::methodWithArgument:andArgument:
```

But none of them seem to work.  Is it possible to link Objective-C methods in Doxygen, and if so, how?  Also, how do I link to a method of another class?  I know how to do this for C, C++ and Java, but for Objective-C the answer eludes me.  Could it be that Doxygen simply doesn't support linking methods in Objective-C?  This seems like quite a shortcoming...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said you tried this one, but it works for me in Doxygen 1.7.2:

```
/** I want a link to Example::methodWithArgument:andArgument: but Doxygen
 *  doesn't seem to link the two.
 */
```

This might depend on your configuration file; I was using a default configuration file generated by `doxygen -s -g Doxyfile`.

Comment: Thank you!  Since you verified that it does work, I tried copying and pasting my sample code back from Stack Overflow into a new file a tested and it worked.  Running a comparison on that and my original file finally revealed the problem: Hidden characters in my original test file that didn't survive the copy and paste through Stack Overflow.

Comment: It also seems to work with "\ref methodWithArgument:andArgument:" but not "::methodWithArgument:andArgument:".  Thanks again!

Comment: I ended up looking at the output (the html screen) to see how it read and interpreted that method signature

Comment: Actually I got similar problem with referring to method from other file written in markdown (not in source class). If somebody will have this problem, here is what works for me: instead of [SomeClass method:otherPart:](@ref SomeClass#method:other:) just write SomeClass#method:other: without any ref or other tags.